# Cucumber Selenium-Webdriver Content-Disposition

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, cucumber, capybara

Is there a way I could confirm the download process of a file when using selenium-webdriver with cucumber/ruby?

When running headless, I use a simple rspec-expectation `expect(response_headers['Content-Disposition']).to include("attachment;filename#{pdf_filename}")`

When I run in Selenium (Chrome), this no longer works. I get the error:

```
Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError: Capybara::Driver::Base#response_headers
```

Is there a way I can achieve this when running through Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the file you expected is present in the download directory:

```
File.exists? "/Users/mesutgunes/Downloads/#{pdf_filename}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much